# Unity & watson conversation connect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson

Hi I'm new to watson conversation and Unity3D.
Thing I want to make is one simple screen that can talk with Chatbot.
TO do this I got watson conversation Unity SDK in my project.
and did what [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#conversation) page said. However I can't make the red dot to green like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb85v.jpg). I barely experienced in coding area :(
How can I started? I want to make simple scene that can talk with chatbot.

Comment: You might want to add some of your code in there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1C5GylJylsIVHgwTmlxaElCWEk/view?usp=sharing         This is my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a workspace within the Conversation service on Bluemix. Click `Launch Tool` in the Manage page in your Conversation instance on Bluemix. Here you will be able to create a workspace. Once you have created a workspace, from the Workspaces tab you can click the three dots on the upper right of your workspace and `View Details`. From there you can copy your `Workspace ID`.

Back in Unity in the ConfigEditor under the Watson menu, create a variable called `ConversationV1_ID` and paste the value of your `Workspace ID` there.

In your calls to the Conversation service you will need to add a reference to this Workspace ID. You should be able to access the variable from the config file using

```
m_WorkspaceID = Config.Instance.GetVariableValue("ConversationV1_ID");
```

Comment: I'm really thanks for your answer taj I really do :)  
https://imgur.com/UiYRFim  
In this section,  I don't get 'create a variable called ConversationV1_ID and paste the value of your Workspace ID there' this part I don't know because I'm not good at english or something...
That link is what I see when I turn the watson menu on. Which part do I have to paste workspace ID? Thank you.

Comment: I did make my own workspace in Launch Tool and I know what my workspace ID is. However I didn't know how to make that appear on my scene..

Comment: In Unity, go to the `Configuration Editor`(Watson > Configuration Editor). If you are in Basic Mode, click the `Advanced Mode` button. Click `Add Variable` button on the bottom. In the first field add `ConversationV1_ID`. In the second field add your WorkspaceId. Click the `Save` button.

Comment: Yes!! It turns in to green! Thank you!!:)

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Visual recognition has example scene and I can run that. However I can't find something like that on conversation. Is there a example scene that I can run with my own workspace? Sorry for easy question :(

Comment: Sure - there should be a conversation example in Examples > ServiceExamples > Scripts > ExampleConversation.cs

[here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/develop/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleConversation.cs)

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you so much  taj
I found it. Maybe it's time to make a scene with it.
I don't know how yet. I really appreciate your help:D

Comment: can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953300/ibm-watson-conversation-service-error-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-c/45953476#45953476

Comment: @JeremyWilde You should take down the watson credentials you posted above. And don't post your credentials in the public like this again...its not safe.