# IBM Watson conversation service error : cannot convert from 'method group' to 'conversation.onMessage'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

I am trying to running IBM Watson **conversation service** in unity and [**following here, code snippet**](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#conversation)

```
private Conversation m_Conversation = new Conversation();
    private string m_WrokspaceID = "xyz";
    private string m_input = "help";


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("user : " + m_input);
        m_Conversation.Message(OnMessage, m_WrokspaceID, m_input);
    }

    void OnMessage(MessageResponse resp, string customData) {
        foreach (Intent mi in resp.intents)
        {
            Debug.Log("intent : " + mi.intent + ", confidence :" + mi.confidence);
        }

        Debug.Log("response :" + resp.output.text);
    }
```

But i am getting this error

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'conversation.onMessage'
```

What i am doing wrong? The code snippet i get from watson official github repo.

Object returning as answer suggested:
[image]

Comment: At which line does this error occur? I guess `m_Converstion.Message(OnMessage...`? What is the signature of `m_Conversation.Message`? What does it expect as first parameter instead of that method?

Comment: @RenéVogt yes the same line, it is expecting object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the response as a dictionary and try to get the value from there. Using a generic object instead of a static data model, you are able to pass more through the response.

```
private void OnMessage(object resp, string customData)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> respDict = resp as Dictionary<string, object>;
    object intents;
    respDict.TryGetValue("intents", out intents);

    foreach(var intentObj in (intents as List<object>))
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> intentDict = intentObj as Dictionary<string, object>;

        object intentString;
        intentDict.TryGetValue("intent", out intentString);

        object confidenceString;
        intentDict.TryGetValue("confidence", out confidenceString);

        Log.Debug("ExampleConversation", "intent: {0} | confidence {1}", intentString.ToString(), confidenceString.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Although i have solve this error buti will try this code as well. And please can you tell me that what is the purpose to log intent or confidence. I think that only response matter in conversation. I am unable to understand the purpose of intent and confidence log, we should use or log repsonse in order to show response by the chatbot

Comment: The intent and confidence above is to show how to get values of different keys in the dictionary. Using the above as an example you can get different objects in the `MessageResponse` such as `output`, `context`, `alternate_intents`, `entities` and `input`. The `context` is especially important since you pass the context to the next `MessageRequest` to keep a conversation going.

Comment: why github code repo has in correct code? Additionally i want to know that why my speech to text conversation is not working by default

Comment: can you please check  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095944/ibm-watson-speech-to-text-service-is-not-giving-response-in-unity3d

Answer (score 3):

According to [line 32](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/fb81974bb6e1905c42534ca0a1d70046c2b4c871/Scripts/Services/Conversation/Conversation.cs#L52) in the source code of `Conversation`, the delegate was changed to:

```
public delegate void OnMessage(object resp, string customData);
```

You'll have to change your `OnMessage` method to reflect that:

```
void OnMessage(object resp, string customData) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but if i make it object then i will be unable to use MessageResponse class properties.

Comment: The common approach in such cases (as can be found virtually anywhere with event handlers) is to explicitly cast the `object` to your `MessageResponse`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx for example.

Comment: Yes i have cast reponse object but it failed  InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Comment: What is the actual type of `resp` when you debug it?

Comment: I didn't check it yet let me debug it. Thanks, i will let you know

Comment: Judging by https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/fb81974bb6e1905c42534ca0a1d70046c2b4c871/Scripts/Services/Conversation/Conversation.cs#L172, it's seems like actual type being sent is indeed some `object` that is a result of JSON decoding.

Comment: it is list and dictionary, i have updated question with pic